# Postgres ODBC connection with named pipes on Windows

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc

I'm developing an application in c# .NET that is connected to a PostgreSQL database through TCP/IP with ODBC.

It is possibile to connect through named pipes ? How can i do ?

Do i need to modify connection string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. PostgreSQL includes a .NET data provider- [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) . Any specific reason why are you using ODBC?
2. PostgreSQL does not support named pipes- that is Windows-specific. You must use TCP.

For local PostgreSQL connections you can use the following connection string with Npgsql:

`NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Database=DatabaseName;User Id=postgres;Password=mypassword;");`

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not use or support named pipes for client connections.